# ajax in wordpress to pass data

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

People, I have a code that I need to include in Wordpress. Can you please tell me how to change these codes to work in wordpress???

Non wordpress code is:

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').ratings(5).bind('ratingchanged', function(event, data) {
    $('#example-rating').text(data.rating);

     $.ajax({
        url : 'rating_plugin.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : { rating : data.rating },
        success : function(response){
        console.log("successfull");     

        }
    });
  });
});
```

PHP

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
      {
       echo $_POST['rating']'
      }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is that PHP syntax error in your actual code or a typo? Also you should clarify what exactly is the problem and what is expected result, what did you find in the WordPress documentation?

Comment: No. this works fine, I just need to write this in wordpress, and I am not familiar with wordpress at all.

Comment: He has working code, he wants to translate to WP.

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress in general its better to use the built in ajax functions that come with wordpress

so add the rating to your functions.php
(something on these lines)

```
function rateAjax()
    {
     require( get_template_directory() . '/rating_plugin.php' );  
    } 
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_PostAjax', 'rateAjax');
    add_action('wp_ajax_PostAjax', 'rateAjax');
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').ratings(5).bind('ratingchanged', function(event, data) {
    $('#example-rating').text(data.rating);

     $.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>',
        type : 'POST',
        data: { action : 'PostAjax', rating : data.rating },  
        success : function(response){
        console.log("successfull");     

        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Since you used `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_PostAjax', 'rateAjax');`, your action should be `PostAjax`.

Comment: It is also worth noting that OP should use [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) if his code is in a JS file.