# Send jquery information to wordpress database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a problem with the wordpress plugin that I'm creating, I create a voting plugin, something like reddit and have the following code

```
$(function() {
var count = 0;
var post_id = $('p').attr("id");


 $('.up').click(function() {
    count = count + 1;

    $('.counter').text(count);
 }) 
 $('.down').click(function() {
    count = count - 1;

    $('.counter').text(count);
 })});
```

I want this information in the wordpress database but I don't know how. I found answers that say something with ajax( I don't know how ajax works).
Can someone help me
Thanks
Jordy

Comment: AJAX basically just means "sending data back to the Wordpress server without reloading the page". There are a lot of threads with examples that might get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078906/ajax-in-wordpress-to-pass-data

Comment: Seems weird, is there simple info or something